# Can I place conditional logic into Celery?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am looking at Celery + RabbitMQ for managing a task queue.

The input data would be a collection of multiple groupings of tasks, ie:

```
InputCollection{paramters}
    TaskGrouping{paramters}
        Task{paramters}
        Task{paramters}
        Task{paramters}
        Task{paramters}
    TaskGrouping{paramters}
        Task{paramters}
        Task{paramters}
        Task{paramters}
        Task{paramters}
```

I'm wanting these to enter a task dispatcher, which parses the `InputCollection` and all child elements into singular tasks dispatched to one of two queues based on task meta.

Is it OK to put this much logic into the Celery code or should Celery only receive singular tasks?

Comment: Isn't this exactly what [groups](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups) are for?

Comment: It all depends if you're using a result backend and you want to group the results too.